# VBA code will successfully run as a procedure but not as a function

Tags: excel, vba, function, procedure

***Issue to Troubleshoot***

Title says it all. I Tried to create a function to give me the average of a value based on a number of years back (1,5,10) from the most recent data entry based on the site name. When I couldn't get it to work through a function I adapted the code to a procedure to step in and test where it was going wrong. I fixed a few things and it worked for the procedure however when I applied those changes to the function it still wouldn't work. It's not a very complicated piece of code so I'm not sure what could be going wrong. Any help would be much appreciated.

***Procedure Form***

```
    Dim StartDate, EndDate, DateRefCol, SiteName, SiteNameCol, MiccCol, PhosCol
    Dim NumRows, SumUp, CountUp, AveUp
    
    StartDate = 44470 '------------
    EndDate = 44708 '--------------
    DataSheet = Sheets("US Biosystems").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value '----------------
    DateRefCol = 4 '----------
    SiteName = "L-10" '------------
    SiteNameCol = 1 '-----------
    PhosCol = 13
    Debug.Print RowCounter(1, 3, "US Biosystems", "A1")
    
    NumRows = RowCounter(1, 3, "US Biosystems", "A1")
    CountUp = 0
    SumUp = 0
    For i = 1 To NumRows
'        Debug.Print "Current Data Points at Row: "; i
        If ((DataSheet(i, DateRefCol) > StartDate) And (DataSheet(i, DateRefCol) < EndDate) And (DataSheet(i, SiteNameCol) = SiteName)) Then
            
            SumUp = SumUp + DataSheet(i, PhosCol)
            CountUp = CountUp + 1
            
        End If
'        Debug.Print "SiteName: "; DataSheet(i, SiteNameCol); " Date: "; DataSheet(i, DateRefCol); " Phos: "; DataSheet(i, PhosCol)
'        Debug.Print "Current Sum: "; SumUp; "Count: "; CountUp
    Next i

    If CountUp <> 0 Then AveUp = SumUp / CountUp
    Debug.Print "Ave Phos 1 year L-10:"; AveUp
    
End Sub
```

***Function Form***

```
Function YearPhosAvePerSite(StartDate, EndDate, SiteName, DateRefColNum, SiteNameColNum, PhosColNum, Optional SheetName, Optional SRange As String = "A1")
    Dim NumRows, SumUp, CountUp, AveUp
    DataSheet = Sheets(SheetName).Range(SRange).CurrentRegion.Value
    
    NumRows = RowCounter(1, 3, SheetName, SRange) 'RowCounter(1, 3, "US Biosystems")
    CountUp = 0
    SumUp = 0
    For i = 1 To NumRows
'        Debug.Print "Current Data Points at Row: "; i
        If ((DataSheet(i, DateRefColNum) > StartDate) And (DataSheet(i, DateRefColNum) < EndDate) And (DataSheet(i, SiteNameColNum) = SiteName)) Then
            
            SumUp = SumUp + DataSheet(i, PhosColNum)
            CountUp = CountUp + 1
            
        End If
'        Debug.Print "SiteName: "; DataSheet(i, SiteNameColNum); " Date: "; DataSheet(i, DateRefColNum); " Phos: "; DataSheet(i, PhosColNum)
'        Debug.Print "Current Sum: "; SumUp; "Count: "; CountUp
    Next i
    
'    NumCols = RowCounter(1, MiccCol)
'    CountUp = 0
'    SumUp = 0
'    For i = 1 To NumCols
'        If ((Cells(i, DateRefCol) > StartDate) And (Cells(i, DateRefCol) < EndDate) And (Cells(i, SiteNameColNum) = SiteName)) Then
'            SumUp = SumUp + Cells(i, PhosColNum)
'            CountUp = CountUp + 1
'        End If
'    Next i
'
    If CountUp <> 0 Then AveUp = SumUp / CountUp
    YearPhosAvePerSite = AveUp
    Debug.Print "Ave Phos 1 year L-10:"; AveUp
    
End Function
```

***Excel Function***

```
=YearPhosAvePerSite(C5,C6,A7,4,1,13,"US Biosystems", "A1")
```

C5 = 10/1/2021

C6 = 5/27/2022

A7 = L-10

***Row Counter***

```
'Provide the starting row and column coordinate for the function to count
Function RowCounter(Optional ByVal RowCount As Integer = 1, Optional ByVal ColStart As Integer = 1, Optional SheetName, Optional SRange) As Integer
'    Debug.Print ColStart; RowCount

    If IsEmpty(SheetName) = False Then
        RowCount = Sheets(SheetName).Range(SRange).CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
    Else
        Do While IsEmpty(Cells(RowCount + 1, ColStart).Value) = False
            RowCount = RowCount + 1
    '        Debug.Print Cells(RowCount, ColStart)
        Loop
    End If
    RowCounter = RowCount
    
End Function
```

Comment: Just a quick question, Why are you trying to reinvent `AVERAGEIFS`?

Comment: also can you post the function: `RowCounter`

Comment: '(-_Q)' It had not occured to me there was a code for what I was doing. Thanks.

Comment: I added the RowCounter

Comment: What does it do *instead* of working?  Have you tried calling the function from a Sub?

Comment: it gives me the #VALUE error and i suppose i could do that too.

Comment: If you call the function from a Sub then you'll be able to debug it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=AVERAGEIFS(Phos,SiteNum,$A7,CollectionDate,"<="&C$6,CollectionDate,">="&C$5)`

This is essentially what I was looking for before I realized there was a function known as AVERAGEIFS. Thank you to Scott Craner for helping me realize this. It has very much simplified the process. I am working with a somewhat older version of Excel with no XLOOKUP so I suppose I figured there wouldn't be a function like AVERAGEIFS in the version I'm using. This dynamic function will help me to view the phosphorus averages from (1,5,10) years to date based on the Site Name.